# How to convert curl commands to axios

Tags: curl, axios

I am looking to convert a curl command to an axios post.
I don't know the mapping of curl to axios command.
Curl script

```
$urlConn = curl_init();
curl_setopt($urlConn, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.test.com);  
curl_setopt($urlConn, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($urlConn, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($urlConn, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "some string");
curl_setopt($urlConn, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($urlConn, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); 
curl_setopt($urlConn, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($urlConn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$returned_info = curl_exec($urlConn);
curl_close($urlConn);
```

Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to stop axios the request sending via JSON, use application/x-www-form-urlencoded. for the payload

```
const data = {:
title: 'some data'
}
const rs = await axios.post<string>(url, data, {
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    });
    const result = rs.data;
```